# Conflicting OnClientClick event and RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: asp.net, webforms, detailsview, requiredfieldvalidator

In the following code I am using a requiredfieldvalidator along with an onclientclick confirm event on my insert and update events.

If the requiredfieldvalidator is not satisfied, the validator correctly prevents the update or insert from occurring. However, the onclientclick confirm event still fires since the button is still clickable. Is there any way to prevent the onclientclick confirm event from firing until the requiredfieldvalidator is satisfied or disable the insert/update link until the requiredfieldvalidator is satisfied?

I would prefer a non-javascript/jquery solution, but I am open to it if there is no other way.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" CssClass="detail" 
                    OnItemInserted="UpdateGrid" CaptionAlign="Left">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="APP" SortExpression="APP">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("APP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("APP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
                                ErrorMessage="New applications must have an App_Tag"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("APP") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                CommandName="Update" Visible='<%# ShowEditButton() %>' OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want update?')) return false;" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton9" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="group1" Visible='<%# ShowEditButton() %>' OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want insert?')) return false;" Text="Insert"></asp:LinkButton>
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" runat="server" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" OnClick="HidePopUp" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Edit" OnClick="EditMode" Text="Edit" Visible='<%# ShowEditButton() %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Cancel" OnClick="HidePopUp" Text="Close"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at ditching the RequiredFieldValidator altogether and handling both validation and your confirm dialog in `OnClientClick` (calling a JavaScript function in OnClientClick instead of handling it inline). I know that's a JavaScript solution but it's probably the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can't find any other way to do it, so I am looking into  the Javascript solution you have suggested.

Comment: You will still have to validate server-side as well, incase someone disables JavaScript.